# SharePoint 2010 Themes and CSS for custom css class

Tags: css, theme

We have a SharePoint solution that was currently deployed to a single Web Application.  Now it deploys to two Web Applications.

The solution has its own custom css file(s) with a defined class as follows:

```
.section-break
{   
    background-color: #3bb1ff;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;   
}
```

The background is basically a light blue which looks ok with the default theme of the site under web application 1.

However, as part of the update, when deploying to the second web application, the blue is a bit out of place.

Ideally, I would like to have this background based on a theme.

Given that the current solution's css is static, is there a way I can use the some of the theme colours for my css?

Web Application 1 uses the default SharePoint theme, whilst Web Application 2 uses the Graham theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enable a theme in SharePoint 2010, under the hood, the default `corev4.css` is doing a find and replace with the default colors by the ones the theme uses.

Additionally, this find & replace is also done for files within the virtual `Themable` folder. Should you want to deploy a CSS file using a feature, you should make sure that it is dropped into that folder.

You should be able to take advantage of this on your own CSS files using `CssRegistration` by setting the `EnableCssTheming` attribute to `true`.

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/myStyleSheet.css %>" EnableCssTheming="true" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>
```

Your style should look something like:

```
.section-break
{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent4-Lightest")] */ background-color:#3bb1ff;
}
```

Make sure you change your theme at least once so that files are rendered with the replacements.

Accent4-Lightest is just an example, as there are 12 different colors and 5 variations.

More [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2010/04/09/working-with-the-sharepoint-theming-engine.aspx)

Comment: I tried doing this.  I added the CssRegistration to my page (replaced the existing CssLink) and changed the css as mentioned.  The colour is rendered the same light blue.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: you need to change the theme for the replace to take place

Comment: Ok.  Does the CSS have to be deployed to the themes folder, i.e. /_catalogs/theme/Themed/7A2303E5?  At present, I am deploying the CSS files to /_layouts/1033/styles.

Comment: "EnableCssTheming works in any location. Only for Style Library/Themable it is set true by default. For any other location EnableCssTheming must be explicitly set to true and the theme engine will process the file, no matter where it is situated." from http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Creating-custom-themable-CSS-files-for-SharePoint-2010.aspx

Comment: btw, if you are making changes to the 14 hive, you want want to reset the iis

Comment: I am running through VS2013 which should reset IIS.  I reset this from the command prompt too - to no avail.  When looking in IE 11 Dev Tools, the CSS it is looking for is /_catalogs/theme/Themed/7A2303E5/adl-general-3BAE8872.css?ctag=1.  

My CssRegistration is:

    <SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssLinkADLGeneral1" runat="server" EnableCssTheming="true" Name="/_layouts/1033/styles/ADL/adl-general.css" />

Comment: what are you saying? the css is being rendered but the style doesn't appear? or the css is not rendered at all (color being replaced to something else in the themed file)

Comment: fyi, there are 12 main colors and 5 variants for each of them. I am using Accent 4, lightest as an example. you will have to decide which one to choose. more here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2010/04/09/working-with-the-sharepoint-theming-engine.aspx

Comment: There is no style on the elements - in this case the section-break span element - the element has no style at all when rendered in IE.  It looks like IE is trying to locate the css file under /_catalogs/theme/Themed/7A2303E5.  However, the actual css file is deployed to /_layouts/1033/styles/ADL.  All the styles used in the adl-general.css file on the page are plain.

Comment: you will probably sort this out by using the themable folder instead (layouts, 1033, styles, themable)

Comment: "Any style sheets outside of the Themable folder in the Style Library will not themed." http://www.cardinalsolutions.com/cardinal/blog/portals/2013/04/ways_to_brand_sharep.html

Comment: In some particular order, I copied the style sheet to Layouts\1033\Styles\Themable folder in my solution.  Then deactivated feature before activating the feature.  At this point, the changes did not take effect.  But once I changed the theme in Site Settings, I could see the new background colour.